# I am unable to import a self signed certificate into AWS cerificate manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

I have  been trying to import a self signed certificate into AWS acm but getting an exception below

> Provided certificate is not a valid self signed. Please provide either a valid self-signed certificate or certificate chain. Choose Previous button below and fix it.

What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Ii had to enter contents of ca.pem file in the box for certificate chain which resolved the issue and I could import my self signed cert.

Comment: You should post this as an answer, and then mark it as an answer so your question can be closed - and help others! Nothing wrong with answering your own question :)